# How to make PHP see my variable as a number?

Tags: php, palindrome

So while i was doing my homework i stuck on one point.

The excercise is based on making a function which checks if $word is a palindrome, from my tests $L works and is moving forward to right side of the word ($L starts from left, $R from right) 
but $R is not working at all, if $R is swapped by a number - it works. If $R is printed, it shows right number - 5.

```
$word = "madam";

function palindrome($s)
{
    $i = intval(strlen($s) / 2);    
    $L = 0;                 
    $R = strlen($s);        
    $pal = true;            

    for($i; $i>0; $i--)
    {
        if($s[$L] != $s[$R]) $pal=false;
        $L++; 
        $R--;
    }

    if($pal==true)
        print("palindrome");
    else
        print("not a palindrome");
}

palindrome($word);
```

I expect to make $R an value, i suspect that PHP sees it as a string, not an integer, but i don't know why. I would be very happy if someone helped me with that.

Comment: from the docs: `strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.`

Comment: `i suspect that PHP sees it as a string` - you can check this way: `var_dump(gettype($R))` and it will show you what vartype it is

Comment: Would it not be easier to cut the string in half, reverse the second half, then compare it to the first half?

Comment: `strlen` would tell you the total *count*, e.g. 5 for a five letter word. Wheras the string indexes would be `$s[0…4]`.

Comment: `if($string === strrev($string))`?

Comment: @Andreas - lol, that's even simpler! Talk about overlooking the obvious :D

Comment: @CD001 yes, but I assume that is not allowed in the homework.

Comment: @Andreas - if it isn't, then whoever is setting the homework is [doing it wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider string as char table, index starts at 0, but strlen count from 1 so if you have 'madam' then strlen() returns 5 but last chatacter is on $s[4], simply use:

```
$R = strlen($s)-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

As a quick, off the top of my head sort of idea... no loops, just some simple string splitting, this works to check if the given string (`$s`) is a palindrome.

```
function palindrome($s) {

    // split the string in two
    $left = substr($s, 0, floor(strlen($s)/2));
    $right = substr($s, 0-strlen($left));

    // if the left half matches the REVERSE of the right
    // you've got a palindrome
    return $left === strrev($right);
}

$word = "madam";

echo palindrome($word) ? "Yup" : "Nope";
```

Basically, it just chops the word in half - reverses the right half and compares it to the left. If they match, it's a palindrome - currently it's case-sensitive though so *"Madam"* won't be a palindrome but that can be easily tweaked by lower-casing the whole thing first.